# gatsby-source-contentful is not working with gatsby-transformer-remark

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby, contentful

I have successfully sourced data with `gatsby-source-contentful`, but can't figure out how to extend contentful queries with `markdownRemark` as it's shown in the official [`gatsby-contentful-starter`](https://github.com/contentful-userland/gatsby-contentful-starter/blob/master/src/pages/index.js#L60-L62).

I added `gatsby-transformer-remark` in `gatsby-config.js`, ran `gatsby clean && gatsby develop`, but still can't see `childMarkdownRemark` in Graphiql. [image]

`gatsby-config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Test Contentful and MarkdownRemark',
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
      options: {
        // spaceId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
        // accessToken: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-remark`
  ],
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "test-gatsby-contentful",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^2.18.2",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^2.1.62",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.6.37"
  }
}
```

[Reproduction repo](https://github.com/iamskok/test-gatsby-contentful/)

Comment: I tried your repository, everything working as expected: I can query *childMarkdownRemark*. Is your Contentful data Markdown format?

Comment: Yes, contentful returns markdown. Were you able to see `childMarkdownRemark` on `body` in Graphiql as well?

Comment: Yep, I only checked there

Comment: Can you please share the query which worked for you?

Comment: I don't have same structure than you on Contentful (I guess), but my query is : `query MyQuery {
  allContentfulArticleDeBlog {
    edges {
      node {
        body {
          childMarkdownRemark {
            html
            excerpt
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: I just double-checked that I'm using Rich Text snippet in contentful. But once I query `childMarkdownRemark` on `body` I get `Cannot query field "childMarkdownRemark" on type `contentfulFeaturedServicesBodyRichTextNode`

Comment: Ok on my side I'm using Long Text with Markdown as Appearance (default one)

Answer (score 0):

`gatsby-transformer-remark` only works with Long Text fields that contain Markdown formatted text. If your field type is Rich Text the plugin will not work since the field doesn't contain Markdown, but you can use Contentful's [`rich-text-html-renderer`](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/javascript/tutorials/rendering-contentful-rich-text-with-javascript/).